# R boxplot Subset column based on value in another column

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I need some help following a big search!

I need to subset a column based on another column of data.

my dataset looks like this:

| Term | Name | True | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | Name1 | True | 4 |
| T2 | Name2 | False | 6 |
| T3 | Name3 | True | 5.5 |
| T3 | Name4 | False | 4.6 |

```
dataset <-
  structure(
    list(
      Term = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T3"),
      Name = c("Name1",
               "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"),
      TRUE. = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
      Result = c(4, 6, 5.5, 4.6)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-4L)
  )
```

I want to be able to subset a boxplot to only show terms where there is a value True for one of the records.

e.g. T1 has a value True; and T3 has two values - one true and one false. I want the x axis to show T1 and T3 for the box plot:

```
  ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Term, y=Result)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subset the data based on the presence of `any` TRUE values grouped by 'Term' and use that in the `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dataset %>% 
    group_by(Term) %>% 
    filter(any(TRUE.)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Term, y = Result)) + 
       geom_boxplot()
```

---

Or in `base R` use `subset`

```
data_sub <-  subset(dataset, Term %in% unique(Term[TRUE.]))
ggplot(data_sub, aes(x=Term, y=Result)) + 
     geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: you wouldnt happen to be able to answer this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66809780/highlight-points-on-grouped-box-plot

Comment: @Keelin there seems to an answer already posted

Answer (score 2):

Base R one liner:

```
boxplot(Result~Term, data = dataset, subset = Term %in% unique(Term[TRUE.]))
```

Comment: impressive base R one liner, upvoted! But I think you need to change `subset = TRUE.` a bit, since OP wants to reserve the group if there is at least one `True`.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding thank you ! +1 To you too, I always enjoy the brevity and efficiency of your Base R solutions too. Edited above accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use `ave` within `subset`, e.g.,

```
subset(
  dataset,
  ave(TRUE., Term, FUN = any)
) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Term, y = Result)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding, this works perfectly where the column is boolean in the test dataset - but for some reason I cant seem to convert the actual column in the data frame to boolean for this to work.

Comment: @Keelin Then you may use `TRUE. == "True"` in `ave`