# Highlight points on grouped box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

This is a different question but follows on from this:
[R boxplot Subset column based on value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66807920/r-boxplot-subset-column-based-on-value-in-another-column/66808079?noredirect=1#comment118097752_66808079)

UPDATED

my dataset looks like this:

| Term | Name | True | Result | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | Name1 | True | 4 | F |
| T2 | Name2 | False | 6 | F |
| T3 | Name3 | True | 5.5 | M |
| T3 | Name4 | False | 4.6 | M |

The test dataset:

```
dataset_test <- structure(list(Term = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T3"), Name = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", 
"Name6", "Name5", "Name6", "Name7", "Name8", "Name9", "Name10", 
"Name11", "Name12", "Name13", "Name14", "Name15", "Name16", "Name17", 
"Name18"), TRUE. = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), Result = c(4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 5.5, 4.6, 5.5, 
4.6, 5, 5.2, 6, 5.5, 4, 5.5, 4.8, 5, 5, 4.4), Gender = c("F", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

I have a grouped box plot by gender below. I want to be able to highlight the points in the right gender boxplot, i.e. the points need to align with the gender of the True record.

Solution credited to chemdork123

```
dataset_test %>% 
  group_by(Term) %>% 
  filter(any(TRUE.)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Term, y = Result, fill = Gender)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(0.8))+
  geom_point(                               # add the highlight points
    data=subset(dataset_test, TRUE. == TRUE), 
    aes(x=Term, y=Result), position=position_dodge(0.8),
    color="blue", size=4, show.legend = FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Distribution of results by term") +
  xlab("Term ") + ylab("Result)")
```

Position dodge now works perfectly if there are true records for both genders. But breaks if there are only one. However, this is the main use case for this visualisation.

The code above produces this:

[image]

Again any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were probably close : you need to use `position_dodge` on the `geom_point()` call.  In order to be sure that the points align correctly with the position of the boxplots, you also should explicitly define the `width` of `position_dodge` for the boxplot geom too.  I also include `show.legend=FALSE` for `geom_point()` here, since you likely don't want the blue dots on the legend like you had in your example:

```
dataset %>% 
  group_by(Term) %>% 
  filter(any(TRUE.)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Term, y = Result, fill = Gender)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(0.8))+
  geom_point(                               # add the highlight points
    data=subset(dataset, TRUE. == TRUE), 
    aes(x=Term, y=Result), position=position_dodge(0.8),
    color="blue", size=4, show.legend = FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Distribution of results by term") +
  xlab("Term ") + ylab("Result)")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much :) works great in the test data, appear to have an issue in the real data. I think its because True False is not boolean, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I figured out the issue - its where I have only one gender with a true record. I need to update the question.

Comment: @Keelin.  What is the real data that gives you the issue?  Thanks for the edit, but it's not clear what your looking to fix if we cannot see the problem clearly.

Comment: Thanks @chemdork123. I'm so sorry I wasnt clear. I updated the question with the updated data and updated output. When I subset the dataset to show only values with True in geom_point line (data=subset(dataset, TRUE. == TRUE); and where there is only one gender = TRUE, the points are not displaying in the right box plot.

Comment: Thanks again @chemdork123. Your solution helped me figure out the issue I had in the real data, thanks again. I accepted the solution. Instead of the subset I highlighted the point by: geom_point(aes(color = HighlightPoint ==TRUE, alpha = .8), position = position_dodge(width=0.85), size = 4, show.legend = F)